# Template (C++) - not sure if correct

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm a student and I'm doing a static library for arrays in C++, so I don't have to rewrite code every time during lessons.

I'm at second year in a secondary school so I'm not an expert.
I want my code to be compatible with all type (int, float, ecc.) but I'm having some trouble.

Can you give a look at my code?

```
// slarray.h
#if !defined _SLARRAY_
#define _SLARRAY_

template <typename Tipo> class Array {
  public:
    void inserisci();
    void visualizza();
    void copia(Tipo*);
    Array(short);
    ~Array();
  private:
    Tipo* ary;
    short* siz;
};

#endif
```

---

```
// slarray.cpp   
#include <iostream>
#include "slarray.h"

unsigned short i;
unsigned short j;

template <typename Tipo> void Array<Tipo>::inserisci() {
  for (i = 0; i < *siz; i++) {
    std::cout << i << ": ";
    std::cin  >> ary[i];
  }
}
template <typename Tipo> void Array<Tipo>::visualizza() {
  for (i = 0; i < *siz; i++) {
    std::cout << ary[i] << " ";
  }
}
template <typename Tipo> void Array<Tipo>::copia(Tipo* arycpy) {
  for (i = 0; i < *siz; i++) {
    *(arycpy + i) = ary[i];
  }
}
template <typename Tipo> Array<Tipo>::Array(short n) {
  siz = new short;
  *siz = n;
  ary = new Tipo[n];
}
template <typename Tipo> Array<Tipo>::~Array() {
  delete[] ary;
  delete siz;
}
```

The code gives me errors when I try to inizialize the class with:

```
Array <int> vct(5);
```

Comment: You do know about [`std::array<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`boost::array<>`](http://www.boost.org/libs/array/), right? And [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: Also, [`std::vector<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: The method definitions should be in the header file.

Comment: You might get betters answers at our sister site, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: *Aside*: You have violated the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template implementations need to be visible to translation units that specialize them.

Move the implementations to the header file from the `cpp`.

A few other notes:

- `unsigned short i;unsigned short j;` should be made local, there's no need to have them as global variables.
- Macros starting with `_` followed by a capital letter are reserved, so `_SLARRAY_` is illegal, rename it.
- Implement an assignment operator and copy constructor, otherwise all copying will be shallow.

I'm assuming you can't use `std`, otherwise you are aware that containers already exist there, right?

Comment: Now it works, thanks a lot! But, should writing implementation in header file be incorrect? And what should I write in the .cpp file?

Comment: @Edoardo yes, that's how templates work. There usually isn't a corresponding `cpp` file, just the header.

Comment: In this way, however, Visual studio doesn't build the .lib file.

Comment: @Edoardo even if it doesn't, a library isn't needed. No symbols need be exported, because the implementations are all visible. It's just how templates work.

Comment: Found the way. I added at the bottom of the .cpp file with implementation the instantiations I need: template Array <int>;

Comment: @Edoardo that's a corner case. You can define implementations for specializations of the template in a cpp file. But in order to define new specializations - the implementations need to be visible.

Comment: Template are harder then I was thinking. Thanks you very much for the help.